# PHP Atualizar checkboxs dinâmicamente

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estou com dificuldade para realizar uma função em um sistema de agendamento,

Segue a foto:
[image: Foto do problema]

Preciso fazer o seguinte, quando o usuário selecionar uma data o sistema faz uma consulta no banco de dados e preenche os check box.
A consulta no banco eu consigo fazer, meu problema está em criar um event changue no campo data chamando a consulta e preenchendo os checkbox.

//

Na versão anterior do sistema eu fiz usando o Ajax, porém eu tinha um campo select de data e um campo select de hora, com isso eu utilizava o script abaixo, porem o cliente solicitou a troca para esse modelo de tabela.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("select[name=predata]").change(function(){
$("select[name=prehora]").html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');
            $.post("ajax-prehora.php?predata=13/06/2016",
                  {predata:$(this).val()},
 function(valor){
                     $("select[name=prehora]").html(valor);
                  }
                  )
         })          
             })
```

Comment: Nao seria melhor usar o input com type datetime do html5?

Comment: Boa tarde amigo a minha primeira versão é dessa forma e o cliente pediu que fosse feito algo mais visual, ele quer que quando uma data esteja agendada a tabela fique vermelha, com o input já estava tudo rodando.

Answer (score 0):

A seguir está um exemplo simples para mostrar como os *checkboxes* podem ser alterados dinamicamente de acordo com o valor de um campo de texto. Os horários são escolhidos por um cálculo que pode ser substituído por uma consulta com Ajax. Consulte [esta página](https://api.jquery.com/val/) da documentação do jQuery se precisar de mais explicações sobre como os *checkboxes* são selecionados dinamicamente.

Coloquei [aqui no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marko31/b6hh016n/) o mesmo exemplo usando uma "simulação" de Ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='predata']").keyup(function() {
        var data = $(this).val();
        var horarios = [];
        if (parseInt(data) % 2 == 0 ) horarios.push("08");
        if (parseInt(data) % 3 == 0 ) horarios.push("09");
        if (parseInt(data) % 5 == 0 ) horarios.push("10");
        $( "input[type='checkbox']").val(horarios);
    });
})
</script>

<html>
<body>
<input type="text" name="predata">
<p>
<input type="checkbox" class="prehora" id="hora08" value="08">
<label for="hora08">08:00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="prehora" id="hora09" value="09">
<label for="hora09">09:00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="prehora" id="hora10" value="10">
<label for="hora10">10:00</label>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```